# Dungeon Defenders - Can't join friends' games (no attempt, nothing happens)

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I understand there's a bug where I can't join friends' ranked (Trendynet) games unless I am also logged into Trendynet.  This is not that.

After logging in, when I try to join a friend's game *(shift+tab --> friends --> click the down arrow next to the friend's name --> Join Game)*, nothing happens.  It doesn't attempt to join the game, I don't get a "failed to join game" message - nothing.  However, they can all join my private game.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: *(I've actually discovered the solution to this problem, but it's difficult to google for, so I created this question.  If no one answers in a few hours, I'll post the solution.)*

Comment: My friend can't join my games when I host, so I'm very interested in the solution.

Comment: Yea.  Please share.  I've been having this issue for the past 3 or 4 days now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Apparently](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?7423-Solved-Can-t-join-private-games-via-steam-friends), this happens when you (the player trying to join) have filters for custom games set.

**To reset your filters:**

- Log into TrendyNet
- Click *"Custom Game"*
- Click the *"reset"* button in the lower-right.

You should now be able to join friends' custom games.

---

Another solution that solved this intermittently for me (perhaps differing versions?) was to have *all players* (including the host) reverify their game-cache.

**To reverify your game cache:**

- Close out of Dungeon Defenders
- Right-click the game on Steam --> Properties --> Local Files --> Verify integrity of game cache.

*Every time* you do this after playing, you will get *"Two files failed to validate.  They will be redownloaded,"* even if there's nothing wrong with your game.

However, this fixed the problem for us a few times, before we knew about the custom-games filter solution *(and before I had any filters set...)*.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an update queued?  If so, quit the game and allow the update to download. That's what happened to me.